# Check if any strings in a list that are next to each other have the same first letter

Tags: python, list, function, compare, nltk

could you please help me check if any strings in a list that are next to each other have the same first letter. Im pretty new to python and my approach was to first tokenise and make the list lowercased. Then I create a nested list:

```
import nltk

myStrings = "Bob build a house" 
myStrings_words = nltk.word_tokenize(myStrings)
myStings_words_lower = [word.lower() for word in myStrings_words]

nested_list = [list(x) for x in myStings_words_lower]
```

Now I'm not sure though how to compare each words 1 letter with each other and make sure that they are next to each other in the list. Maybe a for loop and accessing the 1 letters by `myString_words_lower[x][1]` ?

The output should be the words that have the same letter in the beginning, so in this case bob and build.

Thank you in advance,
Paul

Comment: This might help: `zip(myStings_words_lower[:-1],myStings_words_lower[1:])`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use itertools.groupby to help you with this. Let's assume you have your list of lowercase words:

```
import nltk

myStrings = "Bob build a house" 
myStrings_words = nltk.word_tokenize(myStrings)
myStings_words_lower = [word.lower() for word in myStrings_words]
```

To group them into any neighbours that share a first letter, you can do:

```
import itertools

# define a grouping helper
first_letter = lambda x: x[0]

# get the groups
grouped_words = itertools.groupby(myStings_words_lower, key=first_letter)

print(f"The number of words is {len(myStings_words_lower)} and the number of groups is {len(list(grouped_words))}")
```

If the number of groups is equal to the number of words, then no consecutive words share a starting letter. If the number is not equal, then you know there are neighbouring entries that share a starting letter.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
In [6]: myString = "Bob build an aeroplane, boat and a haunted house"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
In [7]: my_words = [word.lower() for word in myString.split()]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
In [8]: my_words                                                                                                                                                                                                   
Out[8]: ['bob', 'build', 'an', 'aeroplane,', 'boat', 'and', 'a', 'haunted', 'house']

# Iterate over the words and while iterating, check if present word and 
# the next word has the same first letter. (We use len(my_words) - 1 as
# we are using i+1 in the loop and so should stop at the penultimate word)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
In [9]: for i in range(len(my_words) - 1):                                                                                                                                                                            
...:     if my_words[i][0] == my_words[i+1][0]:                                                                                                                                                                    
...:         print(my_words[i], my_words[i+1])                                                                                                                                                                     
...:                                                                                                                                                                                                            
bob build                                                                                                                                                                                                          
an aeroplane,                                                                                                                                                                                                      
and a                                                                                                                                                                                                              
haunted house
```

Cheers!